# TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating setVariable.forEach)

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I was trying to write a jasmine test for this function in javascript jasmine then encountered this error.

```
    window.mainFun = function(){      
        doSomething();
    } 

    function doSomething(){
         var a=["aa","ac","aa","ab","aa","ad","aa"];
         var c={}; 
         var b = new Set(groupTokens);
         var i=0
         b.forEach(function (item) {
            c["a"+(i++)] = item;
         }
         return c;
    }
```

Then I'm getting this error: `TypeeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating setVariable.forEach)`

I tried to test this code like this:

```
    describe("test suite", function() {
       it("test spec", function() {
           window.mainFun();
           expect(window.doSomething()).toEqual("{aa,ab,ac,ad}");
        });
    });
```

yet I'm getting the same error.

Comment: Is that I have add spy, Im learning jasmine unit test now

Comment: You are missing a `)` to close the `forEach` right before `return c;` and `groupTokens` is not defined when I run it locally.